# rowData not working as espected in repeat control

Tags: xpages

I have : `<xp:repeat id="repeatColor" value="#{productcolors}"
                var="rowData" indexVar="rownum" >`
PROBLEM : rownum goes from 0 to the last correct value, but rowData is always the same

This repeat control is bound to a view "productcolors" , a view with a key on product code.
This view has a first column with the product code , ascending (for the key).
It also has a second and a third column with ascending multiple value fields.(second is framecolor, third is upholstery color)

The idea is that the repeat control goes through the different colors for the selected product, but it only shows the first one and does that the number of times (rownum increases correctly)that there are colors for the selected product.

**EDIT :** 
So I have for example a product called "A" available in framecolors "1" "2" and "3"
When I am using the repeat control rownum changes from 0 to 2 but rowData is always the reference of framecolor "1". I don't know why rowData isn't changing.
When I use rowData.getUniversalID() I am getting 3 times the ID of the document containing the multiple value field with the 1 , 2 and 3 in it, which is I guess normal ? But how can I get a handle to those different values inside it ?

**SECOND EDIT**
I tried :

`var testje:string = rowData.getUniversalID();
var db:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(database.getServer(),"product/colors.nsf");
var doc:NotesDocument = db.getDocumentByUNID(testje);
test = doc.getItemValueString("colorUpholstery");`

The result is that "test" only holds the first item of the multiple value field "colorUpholstery" .
How is that possible ? I thought I would get the complete value of the "colorUpholstery" field ?

Maybe because I only have reader access(Publicaccess) to the colors.nsf database ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see a little more code...  like what's inside the repeat.. just to get a better feel for it to go along with your description of the Notes View.

rowData should be an XSPViewEntry...  basically a NotesViewEntry...  I suggest you first do something like rowData.getDocument().getUniversalId() to make sure it is iterating the documents correctly.  I'm sure it is.

It sounds like you're trying to do something with a multi-value field..  are you also setting the view to use display multiple values as row entries?  or whatever that setting is?  That might get dicey if that's turned on.  Not sure.

Again I'm not totally following what what the goal is but I would first test to make sure it is actually repeating the expected documents.  then it's all about fine tuning.

EDIT:  Ok... some thoughts based on your additional info:
I suspect that your problem is the use of the view setting "show multiple values as separate entries".  Each is the same document really.  So that's likely not helping you here.  I'm still a little fuzzy on exactly what you want for the output. Is this from a "view page" of maybe products?  a "form page" of a single product?
I ASSUME you want all the colors for a single product?  And this is a lookup view right? so you're on your product "document" and now you want to list all the colors?
Assuming so...
Use SSJS and the object model.  Do a lookup to find the SINGLE document that has the multi-value color field for your current product. then return to a repeat control something like:

```
lookupDoc.getItemValue("colorField")
```

I'm not 100% sure that's the correct syntax.  The point is you can send a multi-value field to a repeat control and it will repeat it.  Much easier then trying to use view tricks.

If your goal is to have a Repeat of multiple products..  and in side each "row" to show all the available colors then you're looking to have a nested repeat really...  The outer repeat (outerData) to iterate over all the main products and inside that another repeat (innerData) for the colors.  Inside that repeat code you use the "outerData" to get the multi-value field.  Something like:

```
outerData.getDocument().getItemValue("colorField")
```

Assuming I'm understanding you correctly these are my suggestions.

I did do an example of nested repeats like this on an early NotesIn9.  I believe it was this one:  http://notesin9.com/index.php/2010/03/30/notes-in-9-show-14-repeats-repeated/

Maybe that will help.

Second Edit Response:

Based on the code you added you're using "doc.getItemValueString()"  By design that will only get you the first value of a multi-value field.  This is the same as saying in LotusScript:

```
doc.colorUpholstery(0)
```

or the less commonly used

```
doc.getItemValue("colorUpholstery")(0)  ' I might have that wrong.  I never really used it
```

Again if you want to make a list of all the colors I'd use a repeatControl and pass in:
doc.getItemValue("colorUpholstery")  then your "rowData" for that repeat will be each value.  I've seen others avoid the repeat and doing some javascript explode or implode type thing I believe.  using "\N" or something as a separator for a new line. I just use a repeat.  Easer for me to understand.
Again I THINK everything you need really is in NotesIn9 episode 14.

Comment: What do you mean with "setting the view to use display multiple values as row entries" ? In the corresponding column I've set "Show multiple values as seperate entries". I've put an edit above to explain what I'm dooing.

Comment: Yeah... that's the setting I was thinking of.  I've never used that with XPages I don't think.  Maybe once..  I'd be very careful turning that on and using that in a repeat.  I don't have a specific example but suspect weird things could happen. I would definatly build a view without that and try to get your information that way.

Comment: David, it's something like your first assumption. I'm on a webpage and I want to list all different colors for the selected product.Using the universalid I went to the doc to get the colors but the result is the same. I only get the first color of the multiple value field. weird !!

Comment: Mark - I updated my answer based on your latest edit.  check that out and see if you can get that to work.  Post back if you don't understand anything or need more help.